# How to compile C code using sqlite3 library in vscode?

Tags: c, sqlite, visual-studio-code, gcc

So, this is the structure of my project:

```
C:.
│   main.c
│
├───.dist
├───.vscode
│       c_cpp_properties.json
│       tasks.json
│
└───sqlite
        shell.c
        sqlite3.c
        sqlite3.def
        sqlite3.dll
        sqlite3.h
        sqlite3ext.h
```

This is what my main.c code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sqlite/sqlite3.h"
#include "sqlite/sqlite3.c"

int main() {
    //printf("SQLite version: %s\n", sqlite3_version);
    //return 0;

    // Declaration of a SQLite database pointer
    sqlite3 *db;
    // Pointer to store SQLite error messages
    char *err_msg = 0;

    // Attempt to open the "Website_Project.db" database
    int rc = sqlite3_open("Website_Project.db", &db);

    // Check if the database opening was successful
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open the database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return rc;
    }

    // SQL query to create the "User" table if it doesn't exist
    char *sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User (\n"
                "                                         id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\n"
                "                                         username TEXT NOT NULL,\n"
                "                                         password TEXT NOT NULL\n"
                ");";

    // Execute the SQL query
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &err_msg);

    // Check if the execution of the SQL query was successful
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL Error: %s\n", err_msg);

        // Free the memory allocated for the error message
        sqlite3_free(err_msg);

        // Close the database
        sqlite3_close(db);

        return rc;
    }

    // Close the database after a successful operation
    sqlite3_close(db);

    // Indication of the success of the program
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to debugg and run, the programm terminate with an exit code -1.

What is wrong and how am I supposed to do to properly compile this code ?
Ideally, I prefer to avoid using a CMakeLists.txt. I'd prefer to modify the tasks.json file to make it run if possible.

Comment: `#include "sqlite/sqlite3.c"` it seems strange to me, are you sure you should include the source file?

Comment: Include sqlite3.h, and add sqlite3.c to your source files so it gets compiled (Separately) and linked with the rest of the program.

Comment: See https://sqlite.org/compile.html for what you can define to change its behavior, add/drop features, etc.